# TYPO3 v7.6 image too large

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have updated my TYPO3 from 6.2 to 7.6.

Now many, but not all, images in the frontend and backend are displayed very large.

I emptied all caches. processed folder deleted.

What else can I do?

Comment: have you deleted only the folders (from operation system) or have you deleted the records (in the install-tool)?

Comment: does your image processing work at all? do the test in install tool work?

Comment: I have deleted the folders in the install-tool and FTP.

Comment: is IM or GM installed and configured well? (do the graphic tests in the install tool)

Comment: GrapicsMagick 1.3.31

Comment: Test in the install tool is ok.